# RangeAttribute with Enum

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I have the following Enum:

```
public enum ApplicationLogTypes
    {
        Undefined = 0,
        Information = 100,
        Statistic = 200,
        Debug = 300,
        Security = 400,
        Error = 500
    }
```

I have a property with RangeAttribute Validation to enforce the user has not selected the default option "Undefined":

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Cannot select default option.")]
public ApplicationLogTypes ApplicationLogType { get; set; }
```

But when I use the Validator, it passes:

```
public bool IsValid(ICollection<ValidationResult> results)
{
  bool isValid;
  ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContext(this);

  isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, results);

  return isValid;
}
```

Other validation using this method properly fails validation using other attributes such as Required.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, results, true);
```

There is no problem with enums, you just miss the last parameter - validateAllProperties
    Type: System.Boolean
    true to validate all properties; if false, only required attributes are validated.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround advice: Remove the `Undefined` enumeration value. Use nullable enum type and null value for an unknown value instead. Then you can use the required validator.

Possible cause: Your value type is an enum, but you specify integer ranges. Try specifying enum values as min/max or using `RangeAttribute.OperandType`.

Comment: Interesting approach, never thought about making an enum nullable. Any idea why the Range doesn't catch the Undefined / 0 Enum?

Comment: See my edit, although I'm not 100% sure here. I think it should an exception if you're using mismatched types, you should instantiate a RangeAttribute instance alone and call its IsValid method manually to make sure.